# Change the bandwidth control on rsync while it's running

Tags: rsync

I'd like to alter the bandwidth usage on `rsync` while it's running large transfers on a shared Internet connection to play nicely with others.

I thought something along the lines - "`kill USR1 pid`" for the dd command - might work but alas, no.

Does anyone know of such a way?  Would I have to run in multiple times using --partial (not my preferred option)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rsync is on a different machine to everyone else you can very simply change the bandwidth of that machine at any time with the script **wondershaper** from the package of the same name. (It uses the `tc` command to do the work. `tc` can shape traffic for a given ip address, but its a bit heavy going.).

```
Usage: wondershaper [device] clean|[upload speed in Kb/s] [download speed in Kb/s]
```

Comment: That sounds interesting - I do control both ends of the transfer so it could work - thanks